# How to marshall a SIZE structure in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, interop, com-interop

I am trying to marshall the following C++ function:

```
STDMETHODIMP CPushSource::SetSize(SIZE *pSize)
{
    CMutexLock lock(&m_csShared);
    CheckPointer(pSize, E_POINTER);

    m_iImageWidth = pSize->cx;
    m_iImageHeight = pSize->cy;

    saveSettings();

    return S_OK;
}
```

with the following C# code:

```
[ComImport, Guid("1b1afbaf-cb92-42da-8307-5a7be8c2b4b0")]
public interface ISCFHSettings
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int SetSize([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] Size size);
}
```

I am trying to call it with the following code:

```
m_desktopFilter.SetSize(new Size(320,240));
```

I am kind of new to this C++/C# interop stuff so anyone who can point me in the right direction is much appreciated.

Also the error I an getting is:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

This is my attempt at a simple wrapper for a DirectShow filter if that matters. The filter is SCFH-DSF.

I also tried

```
[ComImport, Guid("1b1afbaf-cb92-42da-8307-5a7be8c2b4b0")]
public interface ISCFHSettings
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int SetSize([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] MySize size);
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MySize
{
    public int cx;
    public int cy;
}
```

and in the calling code

```
MySize sz = new MySize();
sz.cx = 320;
sz.cy = 240;
m_desktopFilter.SetSize(sz);
```

This also does not work for me.

```
[ComImport, Guid("1b1afbaf-cb92-42da-8307-5a7be8c2b4b0")]
public interface ISCFHSettings
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int SetSize(ref MySize size);
}
```

Comment: I have a feeling that the Size struct in C# is different from the one your C++ function expects, therefore you may need to create an explicit struct in C# with the exact fields that your C++ expects.

Comment: I tried that, i had the same problem. I'll ammend with that attempt.

Comment: Update with that code, same error.

Comment: `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)` doesn't look right. Your C++ function takes a pointer, not a struct. Could you try making `size` a `ref` parameter?

Comment: Oh, actually, even worse: according to the documentation, `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)` doesn't really have anything to do with structs at all...

Comment: Be careful that you use the right Size class! The one you need here is in the System.Drawing namespace, where Width and Height are integers. The other one in System.Windows (from WPF) uses doubles instead which will not be compatible with the SIZE structure from Win32 SDK.

Comment: Thanks Daniel but that was the one I was trying.

Answer (score 1):

The `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]` in the signature is not correct. The function expects a pointer to a `SIZE` so you need to define this (as you have done) and the pass it by reference without using additional marshalling attributes.

I would expect that you should define the interface like this:

```
[ComImport, Guid("1b1afbaf-cb92-42da-8307-5a7be8c2b4b0")] 
public interface ISCFHSettings 
{ 

    int SetSize(MySize size); 

}
```

`[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]` is actually related to `VARIANT` marshalling but is badly named.

Comment: Sorry Martin, I am sort of newb can you please explain how to pass it by reference?

Comment: @j_mcnally As I mentioned in the comment on your question, use the `ref`: `int SetSize(ref MySize size);` (add attributes as needed) And then also call it with `ref`: `var size = new Size(320,240); m_desktopFilter.SetSize(ref size);`

Comment: @hvd i have update my question with more code that still throws the same error.

Comment: Thanks, martin, this isnt working same memory corruption error. I tried with and without ref now. Nothing is working, i'd love any other ideas.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned already, you should be able to make it work with `ref`, but since you're still having troubles, here's a minimal full program that does work. You can expand on this until you get something that does what you want it to.

C#:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public struct mySize
    {
        public int x, y;
    }

    static class Program
    {
        [DllImport("ClassLibrary.dll")]
        static extern int getX(ref mySize size);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var size = new mySize { x=100, y=200 };
            int x = getX(ref size);
            Debug.Assert(x == 100);
        }
    }
}
```

VC++:

```
struct mySize
{
    int x, y;
};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
int  __stdcall getX(mySize *pSize)
{
    return pSize->x;
}
```